# How to replace tiles in Tiled in AndEngine?

Tags: java, andengine, tiled

in my Game I Create object layers and interpret the shapes in the engine as collision objects...now I want when Player collide with object,
after a few seconds object falls...this works properly but not display correctly and tiles are fixed and do not fall... I want to tiles are considered as objects also fall(replace)...how to replace tiles?
here's my code

TMX file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="500" height="50" tilewidth="20" tileheight="20" nextobjectid="19">
<tileset firstgid="1" name="map_tiles" tilewidth="20" tileheight="20" tilecount="48">
<image source="gfx/game/map_tiles.png" width="128" height="160"/>
</tileset>
<layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="500" height="50">
<data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3YsQ2AMAxFQcsDBfafDjcRrZEQidAV17v8zxkRCQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsIlRjnJucAsAAACwjh8BAAAA3HQyANBlNwAAAMAzWhoAmOwCAAAAeE+ns7U4AAAAfE+PAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPzDBbVpn02ghgEA
</data>
</layer>
<objectgroup name="Object Layer 1" width="500" height="50">
<properties>
<property name="sp" value="true"/>
</properties>
<object id="1" x="19" y="280" width="61" height="20"/>
<object id="2" x="80" y="361" width="60" height="20"/>
<object id="3" x="180" y="419" width="60" height="21"/>
<object id="4" x="261" y="480" width="60" height="21"/>
<object id="5" x="361" y="520" width="58" height="20"/>
</objectgroup>
<objectgroup name="Object Layer 2" width="500" height="50">
<properties>
<property name="fa" value="true"/>
</properties>
<object id="6" x="441" y="479" width="59" height="21"/>
<object id="7" x="541" y="439" width="59" height="21"/>
<object id="8" x="600" y="379" width="61" height="23"/>
<object id="9" x="680" y="321" width="61" height="20"/>
</objectgroup>
<objectgroup name="Object Layer 3" width="500" height="50">
<properties>
<property name="plat1" value="true"/>
</properties>
<object id="18" x="20" y="279" width="60" height="20"/>
</objectgroup>
</map>
```

GameScene:

```
if (group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty(
                "sp", "true")) {

            for (final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {
                final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX()
                        + (5 * mapTileSize) / 3, mapHeight - mapTileSize
                        / 2 - object.getY(), object.getWidth(),
                        object.getHeight(), vbom);

                final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(
                        physicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody,
                        boxFixtureDef);
                rect.setVisible(true);
                this.attachChild(rect);
                body.setUserData("sp");
                physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
                        rect, body, true, false));
            }
        } else if (group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty(
                "fa", "true")) {
            // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it
            for (final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {
                final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX()
                        + (5 * mapTileSize) / 3, mapHeight - mapTileSize
                        / 2 - object.getY(), object.getWidth(),
                        object.getHeight(), vbom);

                final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(
                        physicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody,
                        boxFixtureDef);
                rect.setVisible(true);
                this.attachChild(rect);
                body.setUserData("fa");
                physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
                        rect, body, true, false));
            }
```

contactListener:

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("sp")
                        && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")) {
                    engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.4f,
                            new ITimerCallback() {
                                public void onTimePassed(
                                        final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                                    pTimerHandler.reset();
                                    engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                                    x1.getBody().setType(
                                            BodyType.DynamicBody);
                                }
                            }));


                }
                if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("fa")
                        && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")) {
                    engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f,
                            new ITimerCallback() {
                                public void onTimePassed(
                                        final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                                    pTimerHandler.reset();
                                    engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                                    x1.getBody().setType(
                                            BodyType.DynamicBody);
                                }
                            }));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can try that might work for you.

*Destroy the static body and create a new dynamic in it's place.* This is pretty much guaranteed to work but if you drop static bodies often it might incur a performance problem. Still, this is the approach I would try first.

*Manually toggle the **active** state on the body*. I seem to remember there being a bug in **Box2D** when changing body type where the previously *static* body wouldn't realize that it needed to be **active**.

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("sp") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")) {
  x1.getBody().setType(BodyType.DynamicBody); // Change type first
  x1.getBody().setActive(false);
  engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.4f, new ITimerCallback() {
      public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
      pTimerHandler.reset();
      engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
      x1.getBody().setActive(true); // Then, when timer expires flip the active flag
    }
  }));
}
```

*Force the waking up of the body by transforming it and then transforming it back.* You can try moving the body temporarily to a place far away where it won't interfere with the rest of the world and then move it back.

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("sp") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")) {
  engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.4f, new ITimerCallback() {
      public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
      pTimerHandler.reset();
      engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
      x1.getBody().setType(BodyType.DynamicBody);

      // Store current transform
      Vector2 position = x1.getBody().getPosition();
      float angle = x1.getBody().getAngle();

      // Set transform to place outside the actual world
      x1.getBody().setTransform(-1000, -1000, -1);

      // Restore transform
      x1.getBody().setTransform(position.x, position.y, angle);
    }
  }));
}
```

I'll see if I can dig out the original bug report that mentions this problem.